# Making interface from class

Tags: c#, enums, interface, static-methods

I'm having some troubles making an interface for my class. I tried with a simple public void and that worked. But i cannot get it to work with the public static voids in the code below. I think it has something to do with the enum as a parameter in the method. But How do i fix this?

This is the class:

[image]

And this is my interface:

[image]

Comment: Please use text in your questions always, not pictures.

Comment: interface implementation methods can't be static.  That's a rule.

Comment: If i can't use an interface , how do i use the methods?

Comment: you can use the interface, just don't make the class's methods `static`.

Comment: Hmm i got that class from my school so i didn't wrote it myself. I just need to implement it in my code. Not sure if i'm allow to change that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces are contracts. They specify the method signatures for all methods within the contract.

In your interface, you have:

```
void FFT(/*stuff*/)
```

Yet, in your implementation, you have defined

```
static void FFT(/*stuff*/)
```

Now, why can't we use static? From [Joel Spoelsky](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?dotnet.12.305680.12)

> Because an interface is a "contract" or an agreement between the consumer (caller) and the provider (callee). An interface describes what and how the calle will provide functionality. There is no need for static members provided by a third party. Static members cannot be overridden by a provider so they do not belong in an interface.

Comment: http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?dotnet.12.305680.12

Comment: @viveknuna Is this not what I had linked?

Answer (score 1):

Interface is a contract between caller and callee. Static member belong to class not to the object, so its no point of making method static.

Answer (score 1):

To explain why this really doesn't make sense, the reason to make an interface is so you can pass an object of your class as a reference to the interface type, so the consumer doesn't need to know which underlying type the object is. For example, you might pass an `IEnumerable<Foo>` to a method that doesn't need to know or care if this is an array or a list or a hashset, etc., it just wants a sequence of Foos.

Static methods are not associated with an instance, so there is no object to reference. There isn't the concept in C# of a static interface which could be used to reference a class rather than an object.

If you had other classes that you wanted to use interchangeably, you could get rid of the static and make these singletons.